# Azure pipeline templates - Choose stage to run

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a way we can use only certain stages from templates without using conditions? Like if I wanted to use only the build stage of a template in my pipeline and not the rest of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that using only part of the template is currently not supported in azure devops. There is no such syntax in yaml to refer to only part of the template. For details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).

As a workaround , we can separate the stage from the template and create a `template/stage.yml` file separately. For example:

```
# File: templates/stage.yml
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    - script: npm run build
```

In azure-pipelines.yml:

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Install
  jobs: 
  - job: npminstall
    steps:
    - task: Npm@1
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
- template: templates/stage.yml
```

Or you can comment out the rest of the template with `#`.

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: Yes I thought the only way would be to have separate template files, and call them from stages. Thanks